# Is there a name for "mirrored" layout?

Tags: localization, names

if you are arab or hebrew then the file dialog should be to the right and everything in the GUI should be reversed and mirrored, also menus should switch from left the right if you switch from English to Arabic or Hebrew.

Is there a name for such a feature / design?

Comment: Just because a language reads in a different direction doesn't necessarily mean that the layout should be entirely reversed. Check other websites in your target market and language to check how your users expect to see your product and then test with your actual users to confirm. Assuming that you should reverse your layout for RTL languages could actually make your product more difficult to use in those languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called RTL (or "right-to-left") support (or layout or UI, based on what you're talking about).

Comment: I'm making a website for Morocco so I will need to think about it. Thanks!